# Codeception - different path to test folder

Tags: unit-testing, testing, codeception

Is there any way to tell the codeception config files I have stored my tests in different folder than default. As default, tests are stored in vendor/codeception/codeception/tests folder, I want to have my tests outside vendor folder. just in /tests folder. Something like ../tests doesn't work in *.yml file.

Comment: Storing your tests in vendor/ is very non-standard. just run `codecept bootstrap` to setup tests for you.

Comment: I had ran it and could not ran those from folder other than vendor... :(

Comment: Have you tried to follow steps at https://codeception.com/quickstart ?